# NSWindow resize notification

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

The second example in a course I'm preparing comparing three languages is handling a window resize event.  It works trivially in the equivalents in Java and C#, but in the Mac Cocoa framework, the delegate handler for the NSWindow resize event never gets called.  I added to the header file

```
- (void)windowDidResize: (NSNotification *)notification;
```

and to the implementation file

```
- (void)windowDidResize: (NSNotification *)notification 
{
    NSString *name = notification.name;
    NSLog (@"Window was resized, notification %s", name);
}
```

When I resize the window, the message is never issued.  What am I doing wrong?  Mouse events work as they should.
[MacBook Pro OSX 10.6.8, Xcode 3.2.6 64-bit].

Comment: Did you actually set the object you intend to be the delegate as the delegate? Often this is done by connecting the *delegate* outlet of the window to the delegate object in the NIB. Furthermore, often the delegate is the window controller and is the NIB's owner, represented in the NIB by the File's Owner placeholder.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Ken.  I couldn't see how to make the main window both the delegator and the method.  Aaron Hillegass's excellent book gave me the clue I needed: I added   
 [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowDidResize:) 

 NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
 [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowDidResize:)

Comment: Registering should not be necessary unless the object doing the observing is "far away" from the window. Usually, your NSDocument or NSWindowController are the objects that create the window (in rare cases it is your app delegate), and they should already be the delegate for your window. If not, either connect the delegate outlet to the "File's Owner" in the XIB, or do `myWindow.delegate = myWindowController;` or whatever.

Answer (score 7):

my two cents for swift 5. (showing both delegate and notification, choose one..)

```
  import Cocoa

class ViewController: BaseController, NSWindowDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.makeItListenZoom()
    }



    override func viewDidAppear() {
        self.view.window?.delegate = self

    }


    private final func makeItListenZoom(){
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSWindow.didResizeNotification, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (n: Notification) in

            print("didresize---")
        }
    }



    func windowDidResize(_ notification: Notification){
           print("windowDidResize")
       }
}
```

Comment: The notification one works for me. Thanks.

Comment: What's the `windowDidResize` function for?

Comment: windowDidResize :        https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdelegate/1419567-windowdidresize?language=objc

Answer (score 1):

either your obj needs to be the delegate or you have explicitly register witth the Notification Center to get the notifications

Comment: @Downvoter: what is wrong? I answer why the method the OP shows isn't called