# NSWindowDelegate not getting resize notifications

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

In a macOS Cocoa app, I am trying to get notifications when my window is "corner dragged" to a new size by setting an NSWindow delegate.  I am successfully getting notified of resize events when the window is initially created, but not when the window is later dragged to a new size.  I can't figure out why not.

Here is my code:

```
class MyWindowController: NSWindowController {
    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        window?.delegate = self
    }
}

extension MyWindowController: NSWindowDelegate {
    func windowDidResize(_ notification: Notification) {
        print("windowDidResize")
    }
    
    func windowWillResize(_ sender: NSWindow, to frameSize: NSSize) -> NSSize {
        print("windowWillResize")
        return frameSize
    }
}
```

When the window is first created, I see this output:

```
windowWillResize
windowDidResize
```

which proves the delegate methods are working.  However, when I then grab a corner of the window and resize it, I do not see any additional `print` output.

I have reviewed a number of similar questions on SO about getting these notifications (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169365/listen-for-window-resize-event-in-swift-objective-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508898/nswindow-resize-notification)), and it seems like I am doing everything right.  And yet I don't get the notifications on window corner drag resize.  Does anyone know why?

Comment: How are the window controller and window created? Is the window controller deallocated because there's no strong reference to it?

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you @Willeke!  You are exactly right.  I created a strong reference to the NSWindowController subclass in my AppDelegate (which is where the window is created from) and now it works perfectly.  I will post what I changed as an answer just so people finding this can benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment from Willeke, I created a strong reference to the NSWindowController subclass in my AppDelegate (where the window is created) and it fixed the problem.

For people finding this in the future, this is how I created in the strong reference (in AppDelegate):

```
// Need to maintain a strong reference while window is open
var myWindowController : MyWindowController?

[...]

func funcThatCreatesWindow() {
  [...]
  self.myWindowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: storyboardID) as? MyWindowController
  if self.myWindowController != nil {
    myWindowController!.showWindow(nil)
  }
}
```